# D-Link DWA-125 constantly disconnecting in winXP, but works fine on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, windows-xp, wireless-networking, connection

Hey there, I'm dual booting winXp and ubuntu 10.10. I'm using a DWA-125 usb adapter to connect to my home wifi connection and I'm having this odd issue. First off, in ubuntu the adapter works fine and I have no trouble at all, but when I boot back in XP I get a dlink connetion wizard and the connection times out after every 2 minutes. It's odd because I can actually load up web pages and use the internet for 2 minutes, and then it would disconnect and the whole thing would repeat.

I did a system restore on xp and this stopped the whole connect-disconnect thing but once I booted into ubuntu and came back to xp it started all over again!(?).

Any ideas as to how I would go about fixing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had issues with usb wifi adapters working well in windows xp when I use the network connection manager that comes bundled with the driver.

I have a somewhat old XP notebook that I installed a Linksys Dual-Band N USB adapter, and was unable to keep a signal with Linksys' Network manager. I uninstalled it, being careful to make sure I didn't also uninstall the driver, and let windows handle the wireless connections. Didn't have any problems after that.